# how to create this nonce?

Tags: wordpress, nonce

I need a bit of help understanding what this means:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/#Method:-create_post

> Required argument
>
> nonce - available from the get_nonce method (call with vars controller=posts >and method=create_post)

How should I create that nonce?

I'm trying:

`wp_nonce_field( 'posts', 'create_post' );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you don't have to use the wordpress nonce functionality directly, instead use Json Api's given method in the post controller.

You may try the solution of [bbottema](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-json-api-how-to-add-a-comment-or-post)

> First you need a nonce (Number used ONCE), which is a temporary key you'll use to be able to invoke the API with:
>
> `http://yourblog.com/?json=core.get_nonce&controller=posts&method=create_post&callback=?`
>
> This gives you a nonce number (be sure to use &callback=? as it marks the content as jsonp, or you'll get a similar -but invalid- nonce).
>
> Then use this nonce to create a post:
>
> `http://yourblog.com/?json=posts.create_post&nonce='+nonce+'&title='+title+'&content='+content+'&status=publish (or draft, or leave it out altogether)`
>
> Make sure you have the 'posts' controller enabled in your wordpress plugin JSon API settings. Check this manual for what JSon data structures you can expect back from these calls.
>
> Now, here's the tricky part: you need to be already logged into the wordpress site, because with this JSon API, you can't log in. I haven't figured that part out yet, so I'm still looking for a good solution myself. I tried manually posting and also width ajax but with limited results considering I'm missing a WordPress test cookie in my headers (at least this is the main difference I see when logging in from the site and doing it manually)

Answer (score 0):

JSON API USER Does not work, it will only work if you are logged in to the website with an account of ADMIN ROLE!.. otherwise it won't create valid nonce